# Append more than one control to div

Tags: javascript

Ok this will be quick. I am collecting data in div by inserting hidden input boxes before i eventually submit to the server.
here is Javascript code.

```
function appendToDiv()
{
 var mydiv=document.getElementById("somediv");
 var mydata=document.getElementsByName("description")[0].value;
 var myurl=document.getElementsByName("url")[0].value;
 var data=mydata+myurl;
 mydiv.innerHTML="<input type='hidden' name='sUrl[]' value='"+data+"'/>"
}
```

I have an onchange event that keeps calling the above guy until i am satisfied that i have all i need to send to the server.Problem is only one input get appended to the div.What could i be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you set the `innerHTML="..."` you are overwriting whatever is already there.  You should instead create your inputs as DOM objects (`document.createElement`) and use `appendChild` to truly append them.

Some real quick Googling, but here's one page that should give you the general idea: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml

Should be something like:

```
var el = document.createElement('input');
el.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
el.setAttribute('name', sUrl[]); // not sure what sUrl[] is?
el.setAttribute('value', data);
mydiv.appendChild(el);
```

BTW, most frameworks (jQuery, Ext JS, etc.) make this a bit easier to do, if it's a common task for you.